# Function to replace specific letters won't run with void return type

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have to create a program that should replace all letters in the first
parameter with the second parameter. For example, if the string
passed is “How now cow” and the function replaces all ‘o’ to ‘e’
then the new string would be: “Hew new cew.”... I keep getting an
error at line 9, the return void part.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string replace(string mystring){
    replace(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(),  'e',  'o');
    return void;
}
```

Comment: You might want to reread on how functions work.

Comment: What is the error? Is this in a function? Is it in the int main()? Is the error a compile type or a runtime type? Im guessing its because you should be returning an int

Comment: I'm lost, if you could give me a tip to help get me rolling, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: (expected primary expression before void)  (expected ; before void)  (declaration does not declare anything) Errors I'm receiving.

Comment: @sehe Yeah well when I wrote the comment i was under the impression that this code was straight in int main, not that he was making a function. Is that the what that you were referencing?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to return the modified string, use `return mystring;` instead of `return void;`

Comment: Also, you technically need `#include <algorithm>` to pull in `std::replace` and `#include <string>` to pull in `std::string`

Answer (score 5):

```
string replace(string mystring){
```

This function is called *replace*, takes a *string* as a parameter and **returns a *string***, this is indicated by the type before the function's name in this prototype.

If it expects you to return a *string*, you can't `return void;` because *void* is not of type *string*.

So, you'll need to `return mystring;` instead such that you return a *string*.

Comment: std::replace doesn't return a string, [it's void](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)

Comment: @je4d: Indeed, jma127 confused me! Was just looking it up, edited my post before you let me know... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning void, do

```
replace(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(),  'e',  'o');
return mystring;
```

EDIT: just realized I was talking about wrong language. Sorry everyone.

Comment: A string is not immutable in C++ since you can tamper with its [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data); in fact, with C++11 you'll even be able to manipulate it like you would do with a list, for instance [pop_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back). I haven't downvoted you, so here's another +1 because you've edited it out.

Comment: std::replace doesn't return a string, [it's void](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)

Comment: Apologies again, hard to switch from hours of Python programming back to C++.

Answer (score 0):

not very elegant, but it'll get the job done.  now you can replace strings with other strings-- or just use strings that are one character long(similar to what you're doing in your example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

std::string string_replace_all( std::string & src, std::string const& target, std::string const& repl){

        if (target.length() == 0) {
                // searching for a match to the empty string will result in                                                                                                                                                                    
                //  an infinite loop                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                //  it might make sense to throw an exception for this case                                                                                                                                                                    
                return src;
        }

        if (src.length() == 0) {
                return src;  // nothing to match against                                                                                                                                                                                       
        }

        size_t idx = 0;

        for (;;) {
                idx = src.find( target, idx);
                if (idx == std::string::npos)  break;

                src.replace( idx, target.length(), repl);
                idx += repl.length();
        }

        return src;
}

int main(){

    std::string test{"loool lo l l l    l oooo l loo o"};
    std::cout << string_replace_all(test,"o","z") << std::endl;


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> output: lzzzl lz l l l    l zzzz l lzz z

---

If you're going to use your own implementation, be careful and check your edge cases.  Make sure the program won't crash on any empty strings.